# Sublime Text: How to disable or update color of highlighted pink line?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, color-scheme

There is a pink highlighted color at the end of some lines that is not completed. I want to disable it from settings, is that possible in Sublime Text 3? Or is the only way to edit color scheme using some packages e.g. PackageResourceViewer? Here is the image of highlighted line below:

[image]

Comment: That's signaling an error. It's showing up because you're missing the closing quote for `"Continue rolling?`.

Comment: I know it, but what about changing that color? Or disabling it completely from user settings?

Comment: It's defined in the color scheme as `invalid` or `invalid.illegal`. There's no way to turn it off in settings. It makes it much easier to find syntax errors, so I'm not sure why you'd want to disable it...